# DKIM using MIMEKIT

Tags: c#, dkim, mailkit, mimekit

Im trying to DKIM sign all my emails using MIMEKIT and it works flawless for email body of smaller lenght but when content/size of email body increases., DKIM fails.
Im generating the body using "BodyBuilder".

The following are my doubts in MIMEKIT

Is there any limitation in body/content length?.
Is it Mandatory to give both text and html format of the content for DKIM sign?

Below is my code for reference:

```
var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Sender", "abc@xyz.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Mr K", ""k@abc.com"));
message.Subject = "Hi";
message.Sender = new MailboxAddress("realsender", "realsender@rtg.com");
message.InReplyTo = "realsender@rtg.com";
var builder = new BodyBuilder();
builder.TextBody = strbodytxt;
builder.HtmlBody = strbody;
builder.Attachments.Add(strattachmentpath);
message.Body = builder.ToMessageBody();
```

Comment: you should accept the answer below as that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any limitation in body/content length?

No.

> Is it Mandatory to give both text and html format of the content for DKIM sign?

No.

Make sure you are using the latest version of MimeKit as there have been a number of bug fixes to DKIM signing.

If you are already using the latest version, please file a bug report with some sample code that fails.